# how to merge array object2 to array objec1 without creating new arary in aangular

Tags: angularjs

object1 =[{country:us,code:50008},{country:uk,code:50001}];

object2 =[{empName:scot,id:50008},{country:nize,id:50001}];

please help me out to merge object2 with object1 and final array1 has to be

object1 =[{country:us,code:50008},{country:uk,code:50001},{empName:scot,id:50008},{country:nize,id:50001}];

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_array.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
var hege = ["Cecilie", "Lone"];
var stale = ["Emil", "Tobias", "Linus"];
var children = hege.concat(stale);
```

You dont have to create another variable, you can just assign to existing one as well. You can also just use `hege.concat(stale);`

[reference](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_array.asp)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me I hope you're looking for something like this.

```
newArray = object1.concat(object2);
```

Comment: how to concatenate in angular?

I have $scope.object1 and $scope.pobject2
and after concatenation the final object to be $scope.object1

Comment: `$scope.object1 = $scope.object1.concat($scope.object2);`

Answer (score 0):

Just use array.concat:

```js
object1 =[{country: 'us',code:50008},{country:'uk',code:50001}];
object2 =[{empName:'scot',id:50008},{country:'nize',id:50001}];
object1 = object1.concat(object2);
console.log(object1);
```

Answer (score 0):

We have traditional approaches and we have new feature in ES6. Those are called Spread Operator. Just as the name implies. It means it's putting whatever the value of it in those array or objects.

```
let a = [1, 2, 3];
let b = [...a, 4, 5, 6];
console.log(b);
> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

From:[Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)

Comment: please concatenate in angular way like I have

Comment: if you are using Angular2/4 then you can use this